# Comparing SEM software apps: AMOS vs Stata vs Mplus vs R ---- opinions please?

Tags: stata, structural-equation-modeling, amos, mplus

I have AMOS and Stata, and I have a colleague who has Mplus (and I'd rather not ask the colleague to run my data for me).

I recently discovered that Stata has SEM capabilities. I looked online, but I can't find any comparison of Stata vs AMOS vs Mplus...

What are your thoughts on comparing the 3? I'm particularly interested in opinions about SEM in Stata because I can't find anything online discussing how good it is.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about statistics within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Can't speak about STATA, but I use either Mplus or the package lavaan in R. I steer clear of Amos :)

Comment: @gung In my opinion, comparison of statistical software should be considered on-topic for this site. Who decides what topics are allowed and what topics aren't allowed?

Comment: @mark999 The answer [not intended to be pompous] is that the community decides, in the strong sense that what is declared off-topic in the help reflects previous discussions in the community. You can raise this in Meta. However, what sank this one, as first posted, is the explicit call for opinions, not the comparison of software.

Comment: What version of Stata?

Comment: Would this question work if he/she asked for advantages/disadvantages? Seems like a relevant question.

Comment: @Behacad You're on a good track there. My reason for closing this question was not that the subject might be off-topic (this seems as good a site as any for soliciting honest, objective software comparisons) but because it just did not establish any objective criteria for the comparison. If it were changed to ask about advantages/disadvantages *for a specified set of purposes and situations*, it would justify being re-opened IMHO. For instance, should we be comparing based on capabilities (what specific capabilities are needed)? On accuracy? Speed? Ability to handle large datasets? Etc., etc.